# Materialize CSS reduce gap between Input field and label

Tags: html, css, forms, materialize

I have a form created using materialize CSS. In the form there is an email field, the default gap between the email input field and the label does not suit me, I would like reduce the gap. I have tried the following CSS but it did not work.

CSS Class tried

```
.EmailInputFieldSettings{
    margin-top:-1rem;
 }
```

Here is how it appears

[image]

Here is the code for the email input field

```
 <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="email" type="email" class="validate EmailInputFieldSettings">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change top CSS

```
.input-field > label {
    top: 9px;
}
```